# How to send different parameters to Azure pipeline templates based on the System.PullRequest.TargetBranch variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline template that should receive a different input based on the Pull Request Target Branch.

Template:

```
parameters:
- name: BUILD_FOLDER
  type: string

steps:
- script: |
    echo "Build folder: ${{ parameters.BUILD_FOLDER }}"
  displayName: 'Echo Build folder'
```

Pipeline YAML.

```
trigger: none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- template: templates/template.yml
  parameters:
    ${{ if contains(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'master') }}:
      BUILD_FOLDER: base
    ${{ if not(contains(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'master')) }}:
      BUILD_FOLDER: $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)
```

I tried doing it like this but always it goes with `${{ if not(contains(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'master')) }}:` even the target branch is master in the Pull Request. Is there another way to do this?

Also the repository is in GitHub.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue. It is because the predefined variable `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` cannot be evaluated at the compile time. It can be evaluated at run time (wrapped in `$()`)without any problem. Expression wrapped in `${{}}` will be evaluated at the build compile time. See [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax).

These variables that are marked `not available in template` in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) cannot be parsed at compile time. The document causes little confusion, because it doesnot clearly state those variables cannot be parsed at compile time.

Since the template is evaluated at compile time. So the variable `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` wrapped `${{}}` is evaluated to an empty string.

I tested with below yaml. And the powershell task got executed:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], '') }}:
  - powershell: echo "i will out put empty"
```

The workaround for this is to set the [variable value by script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) in an additional powershell task, as mentioned by Krzysztof Madej. I changed your yaml file a little bit. See below:

```
trigger: none
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- powershell: |
     $targetBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)"
     if($targetBranch -eq "master"){
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_FOLDER;]base"
     }
     if($targetBranch -ne "master"){
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_FOLDER;]$targetBranch"
     }

- template: templates/template.yml
  parameters:
    BUILD_FOLDER: $(BUILD_FOLDER)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of variables can't be used in expressions like this. It is shown in the last column `Available in templates?` on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services)

[image]

What you can do is move this to the template itself like this:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: BASE_BUILD_FOLDER
  type: string
  default: base

steps:
- pwsh: |
    $targetBranch = '$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)'
    $buildFolder = '${{ parameters.BASE_BUILD_FOLDER }}'
    if (!($targetBranch -like "*master")){
        $buildFolder = $targetBranch
    }

    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_FOLDER;]$buildFolder"
- script: |
    echo "Build folder: $(BUILD_FOLDER)"
  displayName: 'Echo Build folder'
```

and then you can call it

```yaml
trigger: none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- template: templates/template.yml
```